# Does the Facebook .NET client SDK support universal apps / apps generated via AppStudio?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I created a universal app via Microsoft's AppStudio.
I tried adding Facebook authentication to the app by following the 'Scrumptious tutorial' (http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/tutorial/).

When I run the app on my phone, I can never get to the facebook login page, because the following line: `await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");`

always results in the following exception:

`System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented

       at Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions options, Uri requestUri, Uri callbackUri)
       at Facebook.Client.FacebookSessionClient.d__24.MoveNext()`

The source of the exception is this call in the **FacebookSessionClient.cs** (*facebook-client package*): 
`var result = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(options, startUri, endUri);`

It seems that this function is not implemented for the phone. I am still wondering how it is possible that the turial, which refers to the exact same code would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not implemented for 8.1 yet. If you want to use Facebook authentication in 8.1 you can use the following approach:

In your App class:

```
private const string RedirectUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
private static readonly IReadOnlyCollection<string> Permissions = new[] { "email", "offline_access" };

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);
    var continuationActivatedEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (continuationActivatedEventArgs == null)
        return;
    var webAuthenticationResult = ((WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs)continuationActivatedEventArgs).WebAuthenticationResult;
    if (webAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        var facebookClient = new FacebookClient();
        var result = facebookClient.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(new Uri(webAuthenticationResult.ResponseData));
        if (!result.IsSuccess)
        {
            // Process unsuccessful authentication
        }
        else
        {
            // Process successful authentication
            var accessToken = result.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}

// Authentication method, this method should be invoked when you click Facebook authentication button
public void AuthenticateAndContinue()
{
    var loginUrl = GetLoginUrl();
    WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(loginUrl, new Uri(RedirectUrl));
}

private Uri GetLoginUrl()
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["client_id"] = "YourFacebookApplicationId";
    parameters["redirect_uri"] = RedirectUrl;
    parameters["response_type"] = "token";
    parameters["display"] = "touch";
    parameters["mobile"] = true;
    parameters["scope"] = String.Join(",", Permissions);

    var facebookClient = new FacebookClient();

    return facebookClient.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
}
```

I put everything in one place just for example purposes, it's better to separate fb authentication logic.
You can find this approach here [MSDN Windows Phone 8.1 Web Authentication samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

Comment: do you know why the SDK calls this function if it is not implemented on 8.1? Is this a recent change in Windows Phone API?

Comment: Windows phone sdk marked `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` as deprecated with comment: "AuthenticateAsync is unavailable for releases beginning with Windows Phone 8.1. Instead, use AuthenticateAndContinue or AuthenticateSilentlyAsync" but Facebook API uses this method in FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync method, so we have NotImplementedException thrown from WebAuthenticationBroker.