# WP8.1 Facebook SDK WebAuthenticationBroker?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk, win-universal-app

I was trying to elaborate facebook c# sdk for my windows phone 8.1 store application. I checked they have provided webview, IE, and Fb App support.

**`WebAuthenticationBroker` support is not given**(Google.Apis uses WebAuthenticationBroker only).

Is that being supported in next 1.0.0 stable release.?

Thanks.

Comment: For now you can use [this approach][1]. It works on windows phone 8.1 (runtime).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307586/does-the-facebook-net-client-sdk-support-universal-apps-apps-generated-via-ap/26360837#26360837

Comment: had done that only currently, as sdk is updated for runtime apps trying to explore it. and found that it is missing WebAuthenticationBroker support which is standard login mechanism of windows.